# I want to know the FQDN of the sender when I send a POST from Cloud Functions

Tags: html, url, post, google-cloud-functions, fqdn

I use Node.js of Cloud Function.
This is part of my program.

```js
const postDevice = (user, device) => {
  const options = {
    host: user.host, //URL
    port: device.port, //PORT
    method: 'POST',
    ContentType: 'text/plain',
    //ヘッダーに指示内容をセット
    headers: {
      email: 'test@test.jp',
      device: 'TV',
      action: 'ON',
    },
  };
  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log('BODY:', chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {});
  });
  req.end();
};
```

I want to know the FQDN of the sender when I send a POST from Cloud Functions.

I tried to verify the FQDN from the device receiving the POST request but could not.

Also posted on: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/pARy7cXJ2Q8

Comment: If your Cloud Function is sending a POST, you are the sender. What do you mean by FQDN in your example? Note: network communication uses IP addresses and not domain names. The client-side must volunteer their FQDN unless they have a reverse DNS address that can be resolved. For HTTP clients, they can use HTTP headers, for other protocol layers, methods vary.

Comment: Thank you for explain.
I do not have networking knowledge well.
Is it possible to tell the sender's FQDN in the HTTP headers?

Comment: The client side wants to know the sender's FQDN.

Comment: If the client is connecting to the sender, it already knows its FQDN because the client connects to the sender. Sort of like I call you on the telephone. I should know your name unless I am just randomly dialing phone numbers.

Comment: The client can not connect to the sender.
Because the client need to configure their firewalls to accept FQDNs.
But I don't know senders FQDN.

My POST request has no referer.
If I add referer to POST request, the client will know FQDN?

Comment: Example>>

headers: {
      email: 'test@test.jp',
      device: 'TV',
      action: 'ON',
      referer: 'test.jp',
},

Comment: Edit your post. You need to be very specific on the application, service, and protocol layer. Headers are voluntary information that can be forged. A firewall that accepts header values can be breached easily. More details are required to understand the use case and what is being protected from what by what.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I have to add more information like  the application, service, and protocol layer to POST request?

I searched about referer.
And I understand about firewall problem.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking. Cloud Functions is a large collection of servers. There is no FQDN for you to use or lookup that would uniquely identify your function so that I firewall could whitelist your function. If you require an FQDN, use Compute Engine and configure reverse DNS (ptr record). The equivalent does not exist for Cloud Functions as that is a shared service.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply.
I researched about Compute Engine.
I will try the contents of this page.
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine?hl=ja

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> Cloud Functions is a large collection of servers. There is no FQDN for you to use or lookup that would uniquely identify your function so that I firewall could whitelist your function. If you require an FQDN, use Compute Engine and configure reverse DNS (ptr record). The equivalent does not exist for Cloud Functions as that is a shared service.

---

You may check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns) for Compute Engine | Internal DNS.